# Centering a ul list and its bullet points WITH square bullets

Tags: html, css

trying to center a unordered list and its bullet points can get that to work, however when i try to use square bullets it doesnt apply.

```
jfiddle here:
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/dL3mbdhq/

Comment: I see.. it's center , hmm.. what do you mean?

Comment: @pedram The bullets arnt square, theyre circle :)

Comment: @BriannaXD: You must assign the `list-style` to the `ul` and not the container `div` :)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Adding a line of text as code to trick SO into accepting an external link is kinda defeating the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did wrong! you set attributes for `div` not `ul li`. try this:

```
#center_this_list ul li
{
    list-style: square;
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dL3mbdhq/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use **list-style-type** property under the ul

```
{
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
#contact_us{
  list-style-type: square;
}
```